# How do I display page content next to a contact form, rather than under it?

Tags: formatting, contact

Using a stock wordpress theme and contact form 7.  Lots of room on the form's right but it insists on putting everything underneath it.

Comment: Remove the `clear:both` from the form or the following element.

Comment: Where's that?  I cannot find it.

Comment: That is either part of the plugin or of your theme. Your browser’s DOM inspector can tell you which element has the `clear` property.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever element comes after the contact form needs to be targetted with css and set to "clear:none;"

Example: If the element that is underneath the contact form has an id of post_content, you'll need to add #post_content {clear:none} or #post_content {clear:inherit} to your css file.

Make sense?

Comment: Did you even read the comments?